# Check if Debug is enabled in Visual C#

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Basically what I want to do is in my program I want to be able to enable verbose debugging if debugging is enabled in the Visual Express IDE. I will be using Define statements but how do I check if debugging is enabled in the IDE

Comment: What do you mean with _if debugging is enabled in the IDE_?

Comment: Debuggging is always enabled, works on the Release build as well.  If you want to find out if a debugger is actually being used then use Debugger.IsAttached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the code:

```
#if DEBUG
// do something
#endif
```